# Windows Form, image gridlines

Tags: lines, image-size

Currently I want to create an application.[multiscreen transitionstrong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3HjS.jpg)
But I have a problem I do not know how to do these lines that divide the image into several parts. I want to cut the image into several parts and these parts you can handle, please at least some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split images up programmatically you are first going to have to choose a file format to support. I suggest PNG to begin with because their encoding is fairly simple to understand ([see HERE](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.4)) and c# has a class to decode it ([see HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970062(v=vs.110).aspx).)

You'll want to think of the PNG file as a matrix of RGB values that you can split up and store into separate new smaller PNG files.

If you want to support other image file types you will have to do some research into their encoding formats and handle them differently.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did. Of course other method as I create a WPF application. [show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKkIq.jpg)

This program is intended to control 3, 6 and 9 monitors connected by Raspberry Pi. As you can see in the image I want to first grid to have 2 buttons. The first button to set the image resolution of first grid. The second button can send images from the first grid to the first monitor and so on all grids.
Thank you very much for your help. Wait a few suggestions.